How to delete directory called [ '.. ]
I am amazed by the things Windows lets you do, then doesn't let you undo.
Doing some programming, I ran a build script and specified the output folder as '../my/folder'
From this, it created a folder called '..   which I am now unable to delete.
I have tried various cmd and powershell commands. I have tried writing the path using escape characters (though this was a recommendation from chatGPT so who knows if it's even possible)
UPDATE: So I managed to delete it from within VSCode by right clicking the directory and deleting it from there. This only raises more questions. What can VSCode do that seemingly every other attempt I tried could not?
What is the correct way to delete such a folder without using VSCode?
Thanks

The correct way? Probably rename it to something legal and then delete it. Or, like you did, find some utility that uses a different method of accessing the file system, and use that to delete the file or folder. I've used Task Manager in the place of your VS Code, personally.

Try the following PowerShell command
Get-ChildItem -Filter "'*" | Remove-Item -WhatIf

and check if the desired output is shown.
